# How do i Declare methods in public and write the code in private

Tags: c++, private-methods, public-method

I have been given this code with the restraints that i can not edit the public in anyway and am not  allowed to call any other library's other than the ones specified.

```
Class example
{
private:
  vector<int> vector_1;
  void function_1(string name)
  {
  "code for function one goes here"
  }

public:
  void function_1(string name);
};
```

is there way to map function_1 to a method in private? so that in main: a method call would act like it was it was in public however it is in private (considering the constraints)

-edit: i have read the rules and research a bit however could not find a true answer to what i was looking for. Here is the code sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MapFunction
{
 private:
 string responce;
 string input;
 vector<int> templist;

public:
 void AskForInput();
 void Output(string input)
 };



int main(void) {
  MapFunction a;
  return 0;
}
```

The restraints of my solution is that i am not allowed to make changes to the public section of the class or put code into main. Normally i would create the method inside of the class by creating a method like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MapFunction
{
private:
    string responce;
    string input;
    vector<int> templist;

public:
    void AskForInput(void);
    void Output(void);
};

void MapFunction::AskForInput() {
    cin >> input;
};
void MapFunction::Output() {
    cout << input;
};


int main(void) {
    MapFunction a;
    a.AskForInput();
    a.Output();
    return 0;
}
```

however i wondering if it was possible to place the methods inside private and allowing main to access them without changing the way it is called in public

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 1):

A member function *always* has access to all members (private and public ones), no matter if it is private or public itself. So a function cannot behave as "in private" or "in public", it just behaves as "function".

Private/public only is of relevance for accessing the function from *outside* the class – either one can (public) or cannot (private) (and additionally, there's yet protected, which is like private except for inheriting classes).

Finally: There's yet the `friend` keyword: By declaring a function (or a class) friend, you give it access to the private members of the class. This access comprises *all* members, though, you cannot give access just to specific members (at least not without tricks such as proxy classes). Example:

```
void outerFriend();
void outer();

class C
{
public:
    void publicInner();
private:
    friend void outerFriend();  
    void privateInner();
};

void outer()
{
    C c;
    c.publicInner(); // legal
    c.privateInner(); // not accessible!
}
void outerFriend()
{
    C c;
    c.publicInner(); // legal
    c.privateInner(); // legal(!)
}
```